# I have reason to believe that a user has created 2 accounts what should be done in this case?

Tags: discussion, support

I worked on both of these questions:

[Unable to connect to the internet via ethernet (using a pppoe) , though it works via wi-fi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833564/unable-to-connect-to-the-internet-via-ethernet-using-a-pppoe-though-it-works)

[Connecting cable/fibre internet using PPPoE in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833538/connecting-cable-fibre-internet-using-pppoe-in-ubuntu)

It's become clear to me through the users comments that they are confusing data they posted on the first question with that posted on the second question. This leads me to believe that it's the same person with 2 accounts. What is the correct course of action to take in this case?

Comment: Flag one of the comments for moderator attention and in the text box, reference this question.

Comment: Could you tell us the user names you suspect? I can't tell.

Comment: @NathanOsman Thank you. I've done that.

Comment: @MarkKirby Those who are asking the questions I linked in my post

Comment: If you mean the picture thing? I do see your point but one thing that makes me think they are diffrent is the way they connect to the internet Gabriel:"Sometimes I make a hot spot on my phone for wireless connection. Also my room mate sometimes makes a hot spot for me from his laptop" Unix_Root:" get internet though: LAN Ethernet cable ---> Wireless Router ---> Wirelessly connected to Ubuntu machine. What I need is: LAN Ethernet cable ---> Ubuntu machine" This makes them seem different.

Comment: @MarkKirby How about the comment directly above The one that mentions the Wireless Router?   I want to connect this without a router. I just have a LAN ethernet cable. Does it seem a bit more identical now?

Comment: Yes it does but it is really hard to tell for sure, I can't even think of a reason some one would do this.

Comment: @MarkKirby     Check the time line and the comment " ** But please keep in mind that those pictures were taken before running the commands your recommended me**" What pictures relate? the ones from the other question perhaps?

Comment: As you have quite a bit to back this up, might be worth going to chat and asking a mod to open a privet room for you and them to discuss this in detail.

Comment: @MarkKirby I can't think of a good reason why someone would do this either. Boredom? To waste our time? Revenge for getting blocked/banned? I can't think of a good reason why someone would log on to rant either but it happens....